# Nesting colour scheme classes

Tags: css

I need to implement multiple colour schemes into the same css file. To keep the HTML as slim as possible, I wanted to add one css class to the body, to be sure the scheme is showing up. Works fine.

Now, there also needs to be the option to define colour-sets on content inside the page, with predefined colour scheme-class on the body. That doesn't always work because of the prioritizing of css rules via definition. Question is, how to prevent this, without defining the classes multiple ways, for each case.

Example:

```html
<style>
.bg-sub {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightyellow;
 }

.red .bg-sub {
  background: red;
}
.green .bg-sub {
    background: green;
}
.blue .bg-sub {
    background: blue;
}
// more scheme-classes ...

</style>

<div id="thebody" class="green">
   <div class="red">
      <div class="bg-sub"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="blue">
      <div class="bg-sub"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

While "blue" is adopted to the div, "red" isn't. I want to be able to use the scheme classes nested, as well. I hope that makes clear what I want.

Currently, the best way I see is using a second css file for the main-scheme, instead of the body class, and use colour-classes of the first file. That means, colour definition are made twice.

Anything I oversee? What's the most elegant way?

Comment: Can't you use body.red .bg-sub in your css? As in https://jsfiddle.net/30cgu7qj/1/

Comment: No. That's my problem. The page should be in "green"-sheme while a specific content should be red.

Comment: I understand now. Do you expect an arbitrary number of nested color classes or is it just two, as in your example?

Comment: Currently there are eight shemes beside the primary.

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/tjegwgy2/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Nope, that doesn't work on multi-level nestings: https://jsfiddle.net/tjegwgy2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question does not mention required browser support, assuming just "current" browser set is sufficient, then this would be exact use case for [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables):

```css
.red {
  --bg: red;
}

.green {
  --bg: green;
}

.blue {
  --bg: blue;
}

.bg-sub {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}


/* demonstrative */

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div[class]::before {
  content: '.' attr(class);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <div class="x">
    <div class="bg-sub">(should be green)</div>
    <div class="red">
      <div class="x">
        <div class="blue">
          <div class="x">
            <div class="bg-sub">(should be blue)</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="x">
        <div class="x">
          <div class="x">
            <div class="bg-sub">(should be red)</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I gather that your problem is you can arbitrarily nest those different "colour" classes, and the CSS needs to honour only the innermost of those, right?

```html
<div class="green">
  <div class="x">
    <div class="x">
      <div class="red">
        <div class="x">
          <div class="x">
            <div class="blue">
              <div class="x">
                <div class="bg-sub"></div> <!-- should be blue -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-sub"></div> <!-- should be red -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that CSS doesn't know which classes are the important ones for determining the colour. There is no CSS selector that says "the innermost one of 'red', 'blue' or 'green'".

So what I'd do is give each of those coloured classes a new class as well that determines they're the coloured ones, say `colour`, and then use those to select on.
To keep with the above example,

```css
.bg-sub {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightyellow;
}

.red .bg-sub, .colour .red .bg-sub, .colour .colour .red .bg-sub {
  background: red;
}

.green .bg-sub, .colour .green .bg-sub, .colour .colour .green .bg-sub {
  background: green;
}

.blue .bg-sub, .colour .blue .bg-sub, .colour .colour .blue .bg-sub {
  background: blue;
}

// more scheme-classes ...
```

```html
<div class="colour green">
  <div class="x">
    <div class="x">
      <div class="colour red">
        <div class="x">
          <div class="x">
            <div class="colour blue">
              <div class="x">
                <div class="bg-sub"></div> <!-- should be blue -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-sub"></div> <!-- should be red -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course if you nest any deeper, you will need more selectors, one foir each extra level, but that shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: Colour nesting only needs to work once. Your solutions would increase filesize too much. I know this would work.